# Using salt hash to convert passwords into hashes

Tags: python, hash, password-encryption, password-hash, hashlib

i have a dictionary of passwords. and hash keys of 6 passwords and a salt key.

here is my code. i read all the given passwords and the salt key.

for the first three passwords i read each dictionary element and convert it into hash using sha1, sha256 and md5 respectively, and compare with the given password hashes.

now for the 4th 5th and 6th password. there is a salt key given. some instructions are:-

> Additionally, three hashes were created by concatenating a salt value
>   with the password.
>   Your code should be able to recover the passwords from these three
>   salted hashes, as well.
>
> 1. The salt value is stored in the file as a sequence of hex character pairs.
> 2. NOTE: Each pair of hex characters comprise a single byte of salt value that you must use. For example, the hex pair a9 must be
>      converted to the byte value 169 (decimal) in order to be used as a
>      salt byte.

moreover,

> ""Do not convert the hexadecimal characters from the salt file into
>   decimal characters. I said that you must convert each pair of
>   hexadecimal characters into a single byte value. I simply used an
>   example in which I showed you that byte value using base 10, i.e., the
>   decimal value. Once you perform this conversion, you will then have a
>   sequence of byte values that comprise your salt value. You then
>   concatenate those values with the byte values of the selected
>   password. If using Java, you can call the update() method of your
>   digest object twice-- once for each sequence of byte values. If using
>   Python, use the update() method of the hash object created with
>   hashlib.""

i do not understand how and what am i supposed to combine with the salt hash. how do i find the passwords equivalent to the last three password hashes (spw1, spw2, spw3). i am not looking for a solution but some understanding on the usage will be helpful. im reading the hashlib library documentation for this.

```
import time
import hashlib
import sys

pw1 = open('pw1.hex','r').read()[:-1] # sha1
pw2 = open('pw2.hex','r').read()[:-1] # sha256
pw3 = open('pw3.hex','r').read()[:-1] # md5
salt = open('salt.hex','r').read()[:-1]
spw1 = open('spw1.hex','r').read()[:-1]
spw2 = open('spw2.hex','r').read()[:-1]
spw3 = open('spw3.hex','r').read()[:-1]

print("Password 1 :", pw1)
print("Password 2 :", pw2)
print("Password 3 :", pw3)
print("Salt :", salt)
print("Salt Password 1 :", spw1)
print("Salt Password 2 :", spw2)
print("Salt Password 3 :", spw3)

salts = []
for i in range(0, len(salt), 2):
    salts.append(pw1 + str(int(salt[i] + salt[i+1], 16)))

# start =import time
import hashlib
import sys

pw1 = open('pw1.hex','r').read()[:-1]
pw2 = open('pw2.hex','r').read()[:-1]
pw3 = open('pw3.hex','r').read()[:-1] # md5
salt = open('salt.hex','r').read()[:-1]
spw1 = open('spw1.hex','r').read()[:-1]
spw2 = open('spw2.hex','r').read()[:-1]
spw3 = open('spw3.hex','r').read()[:-1]

print("Password 1 :", pw1)
print("Password 2 :", pw2)
print("Password 3 :", pw3)
print("Salt :", salt)
print("Salt Password 1 :", spw1)
print("Salt Password 2 :", spw2)
print("Salt Password 3 :", spw3)

salts = []
for i in range(0, len(salt), 2):
    salts.append(pw1 + str(int(salt[i] + salt[i+1], 16)))    

start = time.time()
filename = open('dic-0294.txt','r')
guess=" "
for line in filename:
    m = hashlib.sha1()
    m.update(line[:-1].encode('utf-8'))
    guess = m.hexdigest()
    if guess == pw1:
        print ("total runtime for password 1 was --", time.time() - start, " seconds and the answer was:", line[:-1])
        break
#close dictionary file
filename.close()

start = time.time()
filename = open('dic-0294.txt','r')
guess=" "
for line in filename:
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(line[:-1].encode('utf-8'))
    guess = m.hexdigest()
    if guess == pw2:
        print ("total runtime for password 2 was --", time.time() - start, " seconds and the answer was:", line[:-1])
        break
#close dictionary file
filename.close()

start = time.time()
filename = open('dic-0294.txt','r')
guess=" "
for line in filename:
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(line[:-1].encode('utf-8'))
    guess = m.hexdigest()
    if guess == pw3:
        print ("total runtime for password 3 was --", time.time() - start, " seconds and the answer was:", line[:-1])
        break
#close dictionary file
filename.close()
```

OUTPUT:-

> ```
> Password 1 : 44afbc26b785d9c5cfce73aa06dd0711f2e290d5
> Password 2 : d2e7560d96b0f6ceac88ac8d94f0fdc39d36252d2432ecb1ab510450a93b3c2c
> Password 3 : 95d19ab48d18d4232b87bb086319998c
> Salt : d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
> Salt Password 1 : 955597a308bd22402bf841f19d393526a15396cf49e9477af9f21f45fcfe13c8
> Salt Password 2 : 00b961e20655b8cb16fb7aff3d3a28a3
> Salt Password 3 : bbdefeaebc9ac07b9ad47fd8f9e1b7bf3170bcfc
> total runtime for password 1 was -- 2.097641944885254  seconds and the answer was: computationally-intensive
> total runtime for password 2 was -- 0.6852984428405762  seconds and the answer was: BIzarre
> total runtime for password 3 was -- 1.529630184173584  seconds and the answer was: instructed
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is almost a year old and I don't care if I get credit for my answer, but seeing as I came across this in my own search for this solution, I figure someone else might find it as well. This is a course assignment for Computer Security, so I am not going to just give the answer, but I will comment on a couple things so anyone else might get a push in the right direction.

First, in the code above, it looks like the hash from the file is being salted to try to match. That is not what is supposed to be done. There are six hashed passwords, only three are salted - the spw*.hex files. Those hashes are the result of a word from the dictionary being salted and hashed, not the hash in the pw*.hex file being salted.

The basic operation for a dictionary cracker should be to take the word from the word list, salt and hash it, and then compare to the hash in the spw*.hex file that you already have. Hashes are one-way, so you are not actually cracking the hash you know, but trying to iterate values until you generate a hash that matches.

Look and see what is available in hashlib to help with the problematic step, which is the conversion from hex to bytes for the salt string. The functions are there, so don't overthink the process. Then do what the instructions say - convert the hex string to bytes, and add to the byte value of the string you are salting (the dictionary word). In other words, convert both to bytes, concatenate, and then hash. Obviously figuring out the proper hash function (only three are used in this assignment) and salt order is necessary, but should be relatively easy to figure out or accommodate.